# How can I host HTML/PHP/MySQL for a short project

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, web-hosting

I don't have a ton of web-dev experience, just enough to know syntax etc.

As part of a project I've been asked to provide a hosted link to a small web app in which I use PHP5/HTML5/MySQL/Javascript to leverage various API's. The issue is I don't have a registered domain name at the moment, and no way of hosting my response. I would really prefer not to spend any money just to submit a single project if possible.

Sorry if this seems like a dense question, but time is a factor and the research I've done hasn't yielded anything concrete.

Found Free Hosting Sites Here:
http://www.prchecker.info/web-hosting/top-10-free-web-hosting-sites/

And I'm thinking http://www.biz.nf/ might be the best choice... Only issue is it seems to suggest that it only hosts Wordpress sites, which seems odd to say the least.

I would really appreciate any clarification, thanks!

Comment: For $5 you get a mini vps at digital ocean which isn't even comparable to the free hosting plans. AFAIC if it isn't worth $5 it isn't worth it at all.

Comment: *"I've been asked"* - Asked by whom? If it's a school/uni assignment then your school should provide the resources. If it is a work project then either your employer should or if you're just building a demo for a potential client then you need to be willing to invest a little bit of money to make something that looks professional...

Comment: Consider Google Firebase. ...To deploy your website simply run: `$ firebase deploy` Your app will be deployed to the domain <YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseapp.com ... They provide a free host for your website. You also get extras like DB, auth,.. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [.tk domain name](http://www.dot.tk/) which is free and use a hosting provider like [000webhost](http://www.000webhost.com/) or [x10hosting](https://www.x10hosting.com/) which are both free.